# Sed help - how to exclude certain pattern

Tags: sed

The title wording may not be the best.  But let me explain my problem.

Im working on a data set of cars, that looks something like this

```
31.0   4   119.0   82.00   2720.   19.4   80s 1       "ford ranger"
36.0   4   105.0   77.00   6240.   28.3   70s 1       "ford granada"
```

My goal is to add one space between the following data points

```
80s 1
70s 1
```

so it should look like, there should be a total of two spaces between the data points.

```
31.0   4   119.0   82.00   2720.   19.4   80s  1       "ford ranger"
36.0   4   105.0   77.00   6240.   28.3   70s  1       "ford granada"
```

I came up with the following command
`sed s/s( )/ /`

But what it did was remove the s after the decade so my data looks like

```
31.0   4   119.0   82.00   2720.   19.4   80  1       "ford ranger"
36.0   4   105.0   77.00   6240.   28.3   70  1       "ford granada"
```

So, How can i write a command that will add a space after 80s, but wont get rid of the s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is you want in fact to replace *s followed by a space* by *s followed by two spaces*.

```
sed 's/s /s  /'
        ~  ~~  -->  Two spaces
        |
        \-------->  One space
```

Comment: I see where my logic was wrong. That was more simple than i thought. Thank you !

Comment: No problem! "Thank you" = accept / upvote :-)